# Trying to update an item on the Steam Workshop, getting error: k_EResultInvalidParam (no workshop depot found)

Tags: unity, steam, steamworks

I'm working on **Steam Workshop** integration for my Unity game's user created levels and I use **Steamworks.NET**.

**Uploading a level for the first time works just fine**, I use this snippet to upload my "XYZ.lvl" file:

```
SteamAPICall_t handle = SteamRemoteStorage.PublishWorkshopFile(filePath, null, SteamUtils.GetAppID(), workshopTitle, workshopDescription, ERemoteStoragePublishedFileVisibility.k_ERemoteStoragePublishedFileVisibilityPublic, tags, EWorkshopFileType.k_EWorkshopFileTypeCommunity);
RemoteStoragePublishFileResult.Set(handle);
```

But when I try to **update my own, just uploaded level**, I get an error: `k_EResultInvalidParam`

I use this to update it:

```
var m_UGCUpdateHandle = SteamUGC.StartItemUpdate(SteamUtils.GetAppID(), publishedFileID);
bool ret = SteamUGC.SetItemContent(m_UGCUpdateHandle, dirPath);
if (ret)
{
    SteamAPICall_t handle = SteamUGC.SubmitItemUpdate(m_UGCUpdateHandle, "Update Level");
    ItemUpdateResult.Set(handle);
}
```

If instead of `SetItemContent`, I want to just update the thumbnail with `SetItemPreview`, **everything works fine**.

So I guess **the problem is with my `SetItemContent` call.**

I tried passing these paths to it, but the same error still happens:

- A path to **just created directory** which contains the new "XYZ.lvl" file.
- A path to the **new "XYZ.lvl" file.**
- A path to an **empty directory**, hoping for a different error.

The [Steamworks documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUGC#SubmitItemUpdateResult_t) says this about the error:

`k_EResultInvalidParam`

- Either the provided app ID is invalid or doesn't match the consumer app ID of the item or, you have not enabled `ISteamUGC` for the provided app ID on the Steam Workshop Configuration App Admin page.
- The preview file is smaller than 16 bytes.

Which is strange because as I said, if instead of `SetItemContent` I call `SetItemPreview`, the thumbnail is correctly uploaded, the API call ends successfully. **So the first case doesn't stand**: the app ID is good.

But if I add also a `SetItemContent` call to the process, the API call fails with `InvalidParam`. **So the second case doesn't stand as well**, because the thumbnail is correct due to the previous testing: it would be uploaded if I wouldn't call `SetItemContent`.

I think that's all I know. Feel free to ask for more info and thanks in advance for the help! :)

**UPDATE:**

The workshop log says that it fails because:

`Upload workshop item 2539371896 failed (no workshop depot found)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127469/discussion-between-tyyppi-77-and-tudvari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to not having the ISteamUGC enabled for file transfer.

Enable it at Steamworks > Workshop > General.

[image]

Comment: I was so hopeful this was my issue. After enabling, even after 20 minutes I'm getting the same error.

Comment: OH MY LORD I had the same issue except after enabling the steamUGC I had to replace all backslash with forward slash! What a horrible bug on the part of Steam!!!